# What is it about code snippets that lets me NOT copy them with their styling?

Tags: css, styles, syntax-highlighting, copy-paste, code-snippets

Any code snippet that is properly highlighted isn't copied with its style information. It always pastes as plain text when I paste it in Onenote or Word. Whereas copying any other piece of HTML copies along with it's respective style information.

I can understand it might be an intentional "feature", but what exactly is it?

[image: scr]

Comment: Are you copying from a view-source (and in which browser- this will make a difference), or from a `textarea` on a website?

Comment: @SamuelMacLachlan added [scr](http://i.stack.imgur.com/fLgPu.png)